# No index used in query/prepared warning - but the column is indexed

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table with a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type` char(1) ,
  `status` char(1) ,
  `enable` char(1),
  `club` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3714 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

If I do the following query

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE club='adfsd';
```

I get a 'No index used in query/prepared statement' warning from Mysqli.  Which is fair enough - I really should have an index on it.  I then add an index on club

```
KEY `club` (`club`)
```

The index is made - I can see it through a DESCRIBE, but when I do the SELECT query I get the same 'No index used...' warning.

So I changed the indexname to something different from the column name

```
KEY `clubind` (`club`)
```

and the query works with no warning.

If I build an index on one of the other columns, say 'status' and use 'status' as the index name, and use the column in the query, everything works as expected.

The only thing different I can see is that the column that has the problem is an integer and the others are character.

Comment: `club int(10) unsigned NOT NULL` ... do you see something wrong here?  You are comparing an int column against a string.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being due to a simple typographical error.

Comment: My example query was misleading - my typo in the example because I'm using prepared statements.  The query ALWAYS uses an integer.   The issue/question is why the query works without a 'No index used...' warning when the index name is different from the column name - nothing to do with querying an integer column with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `club` to be an integer.

Your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE club = 'adfsd';
```

Mixing data types often prevents indexes from being used.

In addition, whether an index is used in the query depends on the size of the table.  The presence of the index, even for an appropriate query, does not always mean that it will be used.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  I think the explanation is correct.

Comment: OK, my example was perhaps misleading, I'm using prepared statements and the field binding would have been an integer.  So if the query was
SELECT * FROM members WHERE club = '11';
I still get the same 'No index used.. ' warning.  My whole point is that the query doesn't work without a warning when the index name is the same as the column name, but does work when the index name is different to the the column name.

Comment: @user1199529 . . . If `club` is a number, don't compare it to a string.